# Android activity stack problem

Tags: android, android-activity, history, task

In my application, I have problem with activity management.
Indeed, consider I have 3 activities :
- Splashscreen
- SignIn
- Home

I would see :
- First launch (user not logged) : Splashscreen -> SignIn -> Home (log in valid)
- Other launch (user registered) : Splashscreen -> Home (auto log)

The problem is :
Back from SignIn or Home closes always the application.
But with the first launch, back from Home go back to SignIn.
How to prevents this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code written in onCreate() of Home to onStart().....
Doing this along with some minor changes in other parts of the code will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, set `android:noHistory="true"` For SignIn.

Comment: Thanks for your correct answer.
But I have also an other activity launched by SignIn (forgotten password) and from this, I want to go back to SignIn and with android:noHistory="true" I can't :(

Comment: You can override `onBackPressed()` in your activity (from SDK 7 I think, there is another way of doing it for older SDKs, Google it) and manually start a new SignIn Activity if you are coming back from ForgottenPassword (you might want to set ForgottenPassword `noHistory=true` too).

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
I didn't want to use Keypress event but finallys I think it's the unique solution.